# Python Websocket only receives once from client

Tags: python, websocket

I want to send values from a for loop from the client-server but the server only receives the first value and the connection is cut shortly

Client

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

async def message():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://-------:5051") as socket:

        for i in range(20):
            await socket.send(f"{i}")
            print(i)
            time.sleep(4)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(message())
```

Server

```py
import asyncio
import websockets


async def consumer_handler(websocket,path):
        client_type = await websocket.recv()
        print(client_type)



start_server = websockets.serve(consumer_handler,"ws://-------:5051", 5051)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 2):

So, your `consumer_handler` receives message once and finishes.
You need to add loop.
Try something like this:

```py
async def consumer_handler(websocket, path):
    async for msg in websocket:
        print(msg)
```

Comment: thanks a bunch,  i think that should work also ,but actually found out my socket was closing for some weird reason so i added  a socket time-out of None that way the connection wasn't cut , i guess that's why i could only print one message before the whole thing broke down